# How to route NextJS page to SPA (Single Page Application)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-page-application

I am building a SaaS application using Next JS. I am wishing to take advantage of SSG for SEO on landing pages, pricing etc. However for the actual application I am wishing to use a SPA since its highly interactive and do not wish to use SSR (at least initially) since I have more past experience with SPA (and don't want the server costs to begin).

My desire is to have https://example.com/ (in pages folder) render the SPA (route to SPA/index.tsx which is the default create react app entry point) if the user is logged in.

essentially:

```
pages/index.tsx
imports...

export default function Home() {
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    route to SPA
  }
  
  return <LandingPage>
}
```

Example file structure

Pages

- index.tsx
- _app.tsx
- _document.tsx
- dashboard

SPA

- index.tsx
- App.tsx

Any advice or help on how to do this would be great.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I ended up using was to use a subdomain.

E.g. host the next app with landing pages etc on example.com and then host the react app on app.example.com. Once a user signs in redirect them to app.example.com which still has access to the auth session.

Comment: Excuse me, your approach interests me. May I ask about your project structure, as here you nested 2 separate projects of `ReactJS` & `NextJS` under a same wrapper folder (both has its own **/public**, **index.tsx**,...), or another way? Which file is considered as the entry point of the app (`_app.tsx` or `index.tsx`)? Thank you!

Comment: Hey no worries :). So in choosing to use subdomains I also split the directories. They now both operate independently and will be deployed separately. However cookies can be stored across subdomains if set to do so. That way I have all landing pages and authorization in my next app. I then redirect to the SPA which is hosted at app.example.com.

Comment: Nice idea! And also thanks for sharing about the idea of storing cookies across domain & subdomains. I haven't thought before.